# Do not know how to solve this Error: TypeError: add_sudoku_field() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sudokufield'

Tags: python

I cannot find my mistake. Can anybody help me?

```
new_sudoku_field = SudokuField.SudokuField(i)
#Code to generate j
self.__rows[j].add_sudoku_field(new_sudoku_field)
```

I get following message

```
TypeError: add_sudoku_field() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sudokufield'
```

The method add_sudoku_field() is defined:

```
def add_sudoku_field(self, sudokufield): 
    self.__list_sudoku_fields.append(sudokufield)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to call static method which is also a constructor SudokuField.
When creating new sudoku filed just call your constructor like this

```
new_sudoku_filed = SudokuField(i)
```

Comment: SudokuField is in another Module called SudokuField:
so SudokuField(Module name).SudokuField(i) (Constructor)